# How to access getters and setter inside a stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

I have a method that takes a json object and insert it to aws elastic search service but i want to write another method that takes multiple json objects and insert them to aws elastic search

```
/**
 * Create the Product in ElasticSearch
 *
 * @param product The Product
 * @return The response string
 * @throws JsonProcessingException Throws JsonProcessingException when response cannot be parsed
 */
public String createNewProduct(Product product) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(product);
    if (json != null) {
        AwsResponse response = createDocument(ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_INDEX,
            ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_DOCUMENT_TYPE,
            json,
            product.getPartNo());
        // Creating a new document not seen before results in a 201 status, where as overwriting a previous document results in a 200
        if (response != null && (response.getHttpResponse().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
            || response.getHttpResponse().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK.value())) {
            LOGGER.info("Successfully created new Product", product.getPartNo(), product.getLevelOne());
            return product.getPartNo();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Create new Products in ElasticSearch
 * @param products The product
 * @throws JsonProcessingException Throws JsonProcessingException when response cannot be parsed
 */
public String createNewProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) throws JsonProcessingException{
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    products.stream()
        .map(product -> {
          try {
              return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(product);
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              return new JsonProcessingException(e){};
          }
      })
      .forEach(product -> {
          createDocument(ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_INDEX,
              ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_DOCUMENT_TYPE,
              product,
              products.stream().forEach(p->p::getPartNo)
              );
      });




    return null;
}
```

As you see createDocument methods takes 4 paramaters 4 of them are string
The first method works really well but second method has a problem.
When i try to get partNo's it gives me an error as normal "void is not functional interface" how can i make it work.

Comment: Either `Product::getPartNo` or `p->p.getPartNo()` .. Or rather the problem in your case should be the signature of the method in use `createDocument`, shouldn't that be called with just a single `product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `map` operation, a `forEach` could work in your case. The use of `stream`s is not very effective either in this case. You could have simply written a `for` loop and performed the operation as :

```
for (Product product : products) {
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(product);
    // handle the exception as well above
    createDocument(ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_INDEX,
            ElasticSearchConstants.PRODUCTS_DOCUMENT_TYPE,
            json, product.getPartNo());
}
```

Comment: ah i see but i am new at streams so i am trying to improve my skills on it, thank you